# Java jks keystore with CA, intermediate and website cert on tomcat in docker on AWS gives "Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognised"

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, firefox, docker

I have put together a jks keystore and Java 1.8 cacerts with a certificate from my company's certificate provider for internal use only, and build it into my app's docker build with tomcat, deployed it and successfully started the server and connected to it via Chrome and Edge, but Firefox on Windows 10 is not connecting, giving SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER "Your connection is not secure" and "Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognised".

This is what I've done:

1. I created my private key and certificate request using the Java 1.8 keytool.
2. Obtained a root certificate .cer, an intermediate .cer and a website .cer file
3. I put the root cert into java's cacerts:

```sh
keytool -importcert -alias app-cert1 -file AD1GXECA001-SHA2-Root.cer -v -keystore c:/dev/tools/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/security/cacer
```

ts

4. I also concatenated them together into a pem file in this order:

   ```
   1. website cert
   2. intermediate cert
   3. company cert
   ```
5. and inserted them into the jks with keytool:

```sh
keytool -import -alias app-cert1 -file chain.pem -v -keystore my-app.jks
```

6. and I build them into my docker image which runs a Spring boot fat jar with tomcat and the app inside:

```sh
CMD -Dlogging.file=/logs/my-app.log 
    -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/config/login.conf
    -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/config/krb5.conf
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/config/cacerts
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
    -Djavax.net.debug=ssl
    -jar /my-app.jar
```

and the Spring config:

```sh
server.ssl.key-alias=app-cert1
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store=file:/config/my-app.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

I see no errors in the build or the tomcat logging.

Where is my problem? Firefox? Windows 10? Docker?

Are Chrome and Edge really not having problems? Does that mean it must be firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message simply means that Firefox cannot establish a chain starting from a trusted certificate in its certificate store (usually the root CA) down to the website certificate.

As you have imported the complete chain (excluding the root CA) in Tomcat's SSL keystore, Tomcat will deliver those certificates to the client. So, you are fine on the server side. But on the client side (Firefox in this case) you need a trust anchor, so you have to import the root certificate into Firefox.

The reason you are getting different results with Chrome/Edge is that Firefox has its own certificate store, whereas Chrome and Edge use the Windows store.

Comment: OK so that is the problem. This is the answer: [How to make FF trust system CA certificates](https://serverfault.com/questions/722563/how-to-make-firefox-trust-system-ca-certificates) - you have to set security.enterprise_roots.enabled=true into FF's about:config